# how to get text from multiple edit text with the same id in android

Tags: android

I am creating an edit text filed using xml and adding that in listview 's adapter class .i m using enumerator.by this i was able to create two textfields with the same id.the problem is how to get the strings from both the text fields since they are sharing the same id.below is the code.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = null;

    AddKeywordRow row = keywordRows.get(position);

    switch (row.getRowType()) {
    case TitleRow:
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.titlerow, null);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowtitle);
        txtTitle.setText(row.getMessage());
        break;
    case EditRow:
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.editrow, null);
        txtInput = (EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowedit);
        txtInput.setHint(row.getMessage());
        if (row.getHeight() != 0)
        {
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,row.getHeight());
            txtInput.setLayoutParams(layoutParams); 
            layoutParams.setMargins(7, 0, 7,0);
        //txtInput.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            //      LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, row.getHeight()));
            txtInput.setPadding(3,0,0,30);  
        }
        // set padding and margin
        break;
    case MessageRow:
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.messagerow, null);
        TextView txtMessage = (TextView) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.rowmessage);
        txtMessage.setText(row.getMessage());
        break;
    case ButtonRow:
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.buttonrow, null);
        Button btn = (Button)rowView.findViewById(R.id.button1);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        }
        });

        break;
    }

    return rowView;
}
```

Comment: There is no easy way to do this I think. You have to go through every child of your listview and check if it has that ID, if this is the approach you want. Maybe consider using something else then listview for this.. It is not meant to be used this way.. But is meant to be used to create a list of same items.. like a table with tabular data.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would recomend you to use [Holder pattern](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterperformance_hoder) for your list items.
Secondly override getItem(int position); in your adapter so that it returns necessary text value depending on position. You will be able to use it in your onItemclickListener() within your activity for example.

```
@Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return keywordRows.getMessage(position);
    }
```

And your onItemClickListener will look like:

```
private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long rowid) {
            String message = (String)adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve them by list row, something like (pseudo code) :

((EditText)getAdapter().getItem(id)).getText()

Comment: could u gimme an example of it using the above code..would u grateful..i want to store it in two different string